# Is this the latest version of the maven scala plugin ?

Tags: scala, maven

Is this the latest version of the maven scala plugin : http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/

It states '© 2010 Scala Tools' so there must be a later version at another location ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The last version is at http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin/index.html

The plugin was renamed to scala-maven-plugin to respect the new maven naming policy for plugins. (ie only maven core plugins are prefixed maven)